# Basic iOS Decimal Trim

Tags: ios, swift

I have float value 1.96, then I want to display 1.9 as string, if I use String(format: "%.1f") the result is 2.0, also I try to use NumberFormatter as extension

```
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1

    return formatter.string(for:  self)!
```

But still the result 2.0

is there any best way to achieved  1.96 to 1.9?

Comment: If you want truncation you may have to do more work than rounded approximations which is what most people would expect to happen. 1.96 rounds up to 2.0.

Comment: Set the rounding method on the number formatter.

Answer (score 1):

Old trick:

```
var yourResult = Double(floor(10*yourDecimalDigit)/10)

// yourResult = 1.9
```

Convert to string like this

```
var string = String(yourResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use general extension of Double to truncate the double value.

**Swift 4.0**

```
extension Double {
    func truncate(places : Int)-> Double {
        return Double(floor(pow(10.0, Double(places)) * self)/pow(10.0, Double(places)))
    }
}
```

Use it like this below

```
let trimedValue = 1.96.truncate(places: 1) // 1.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's methods can help you but I like to do it by myself

extension :

```
extension CGFloat{

    var onlyOneDigits : String {
        var str = "\(self)"
        let count = str.count 
        if self >= 1000 && self < 10000{
            str.removeLast(count - 6)
            return str
        }else if self >= 100{
            str.removeLast(count - 5)
            return str
        }else if self >= 10{
            str.removeLast(count - 4)
            return str
        }else{
            str.removeLast(count - 3)
            return str
        }
    }
}
```

Use it :

```
        let myFloat : CGFloat = 1212.1212
        let myStr : String = myFloat.onlyOneDigits
        print(myStr) // 1212.1

        let anotherFloat : CGFloat = 1.96
        let anotherStr : String = anotherFloat.onlyOneDigits
        print(anotherStr) // 1.9
```